# jQuery: Change font size with slider as soon as it is activated - how?

Tags: jquery, slider, font-size

I'm trying to make a font size slider, allowing the user to resize the font with a slider. Simple script that works:

Slider:

```
<input type="range" min="100" max="200" id="slider">
```

jQuery script:

```
$('#slider').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#text').css("font-size", (val + "%"));           
});
```

This works perfect except I would like it to be more dynamic, so that the text start resizing as soon as the slider is moved insted of "activating" when the slider is released.

How do I do this?

/C80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change 'change' to 'input'

```
$('#slider').on('input', function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   $('#text').css("font-size", (val + "%"));           
});
```

Comment: Of course - such a simple solution - embarrasing that I missed it. Thanks a lot! Still a jQuery noob.